# How to select data From Table only registred after specified time?

Tags: sql

I want to select only the lines recorded from a certain time.

For exemple :

```
Select * from my table where Time1 > 14:00
```

I have a column `time1` in my table

Answer (score -1):

Date compares requires you to change column to date type, otherwise it will compare a string.

In the case below, myDataColumn is date type and it works properly in order to compare dates.

example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myDataColumn > 2021-10-01
```

You can also transform your date into a integer like "202110011351" and then compare like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myDataColumn > 202110011351
```

Which is basically dates that's bigger than 2021-10-01 13:51

Comment: Thank you Lucas ... its working when i changed Time1 to date type

Comment: You can click on the question as solved to mark my answer to help other, since it helped you